# How do I re-position and ImageView on a layout with a TextInputLayout and EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an trash can icon I am using as a drawable in an ImageView.  The trash can shows up at the top of the layout line which I don't want (Pic 1).  Adding 'layout_gravity="bottom"' moves the icon down all the way to the bottom of the layout (Pic 2).  I would like the icon to be placed to exactly match the horizontal bottom of the "Due Date" text and to the left, just to the right of the end of the Due Date EditText Line (Pic3).  I tried adding margins and padding but no luck.  Any ideas?

partial xml file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="Trash can"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"  />
...
```

[image]   Pic1

[image]   Pic2

[image]   Pic 3

[image]   Pic 4

Comment: Try (android:layout_marginRight="xdp" & android:layout_marginTop="xdp") otherwise you may need a FrameLayout surrounding the ImageView, then you should be able to position the Bin anywhere you want.

Comment: Ok, but how would I make "Due Date" EditText take up 90% of the width and the trash can take up the remaining 10%?

Comment: you cant, android doesnt use percentages as far as i know. you could however use a table layout and split the columns to difernet sizes so the edit text takes more horizontal space

Comment: ok thanks, I will try that.

Comment: You can set margin in your image in photoshop also

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
trashIcon.setY(dateEdittext.getY-dateEdittext.getHeight/2);
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do that within xml layout file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout weights to make sure the trash can only uses what it needs (0) and gives the rest to the edit text (1)

```
<LinearLayout
  <EditText
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
  />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:contentDescription="Trash can"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok that works, however there is quite a bit of blank space between the end of the EditText and icon (see pic 4 above).  So there must be some default margins or padding at the end of the EditText and/or the beginning and end of the ImageView.  Will setting margins and padding explicitly to zero help in this case?  Any other ideas?

Comment: Also, is there any downside to using a TextView with a drawable versus your recommended ImageView with the src=drawable...?